# Why is TypeScript not returning APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2 for an api handler wrapped in another handler?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a function which wraps aws lambda handlers and performs some logging. The lambdas are linked to API gateway so I've been using the `APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2` type from the [@types/aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) package.

The function I have looks something like the below.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 } from "aws-lambda";

const wrapApiHandler = (apiHandler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2) => {
  const wrappedHandler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (
    event,
    context,
    callback
  ) => {
    try {
      const result = await apiHandler(
        event,
        context,
        callback
      );

      console.log(result);

      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);

      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: "Failed to process request",
        }),
      };
    }
  };

  return wrappedHandler;
};
```

When I try to do the above TypeScript complains about the `wrappedHandler` with the message below.

```
Type '(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2, context: Context, callback: Callback<APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2<never>'.
  Type 'Promise<void | APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>>'.
    Type 'Promise<void | APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>>'.
      Type 'void | APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>' is not assignable to type 'APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>'.
        Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'APIGatewayProxyResultV2<never>'.ts(2322)
```

What I need is for the TypeScript to recognise that a `APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2` type is returned but I don't see why this isn't happening.

I can see the following...

```
type APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2<T = never> = Handler<APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T>>;

export type APIGatewayProxyResultV2<T = never> = APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2 | string | T;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: just return an object from your function ... `return {}`.